# How do you remove <li> from a <ul> by Id?

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<ul id="ulId">
    <li id="firstli">
    </li>
    <li id="secondli">
    </li>
</ul>
```

and I am trying to remove `secondli`.

This is what I have tried based on some reading.

```
$('#ulId secondli').remove();
```

and

```
$('#ulId > secondli').remove();
```

but these 2 methods did not work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The ID is unique, as you see, if you try $('#secondli').remove();, it will work.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#secondli').remove();
```

In jQuery, you refer to the ID of an element with a `#` in front of it. See http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: Is there a way to specify which Ul it's coming from?

Comment: Yes, you can specify the UL's ID in front of it, however since IDs on all elements must be unique, there shouldn't be any need to be more specific.

Comment: +1 for this line "In jQuery, you refer to the ID of an element with a # in front of it."

Comment: It's *almost* like jQuery selector syntax is very closely related to standard CSS selectors .. that is: "In CSS, you refer to the ID of an element with a # in front of it."

Comment: I believe this to be the correct answer but I just want to let everyone know that my problem was that my id had a period in it which I did not mention in the question.  This has to be escaped with a "\\".  For example `$('#ulid #li\\.toRemove');`

Comment: @Pittfall I would recommend avoid using a `.` in an ID. While [it *is* permitted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) in both HTML4/5 it is somewhat confusing and may lead to strange behavior in tools which do not otherwise account for it. Consider using either `_` or a `-` as a "more conventional" word separator.

Answer (score 6):

This will work for you

```
$('#secondli').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a space between the select the li element,

```
$('#second li').remove(); // when referencing by id
```

or

```
$(".second li").remove(); // when referencing by class
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#ulId #secondli').remove();`

Select the container `#ulId` and then the list item `#secondli`. You had forgotten to add the ID tag before the second li.

Answer (score 0):

if you want remove an `<li>` with ID try :

`$('#yourlist #yourli').remove()`;

otherwise, if you would remove an `<li>` based on the content you can use :

`$('#yourlist li:contains("TextToRemove")').remove();`