# how to remove li with input of specific id from ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unsorted list with **inputs**. I am wondering how I can remove an input from the list provided specific id of the input.
Here is the sample list:

```
     <ul class="list>
        <li class="item"><input class="child" id"1" type"checkbox" name ="checkbox">"test 1"</li>
        <li class="item"><input class="child" id"2" type"checkbox" name ="checkbox">"test 2"</li>
        <li class="item"><input class="child" id"3" type"checkbox" name ="checkbox">"test 3"</li>
    </ul>
```

This is  not the same as the proposed solution as  I have inputs involved inside the li and not just li directly

Comment: did you even try something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove and <li> from a <ul> by Id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624690/how-do-you-remove-and-li-from-a-ul-by-id)

Comment: All you have to do is to query the `input` by id, then find it's closest `li` parent with jQuery, and remove it. See my answer below :-)

Comment: it is not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
function removeOption(id){
  $('input#' + id).closest('li').remove();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just changed it to '$('.child#' + id).closest('li').remove();' as i had other inputs in the code.

Comment: There is actually no reason for the 'input' in the selector, since the `#id` is (supposed to be) unique on the page, and the `id` selector performs much better.

Comment: you said it "supposed to be", its just another safegaurd

Comment: Ok i got your point, but it's not our decision to make which one he chooses. Mine can be a bit slower but not by much, if you can say how many performance you're going to loose be my guest to make the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find your input (by id), then go to it's closest `li` parent, and remove it:

```
$('#your-input-id').closest('li').remove();
```